# Is Energy stored work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

Energy is the ability to do work therefore Energy should be the primitive form of work. But I cant find any conformation, if wrong can anyone explain to me the relationships between Work, energy, and force in order of causality.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "primitive form of work" ? Energy is the capacity to do work; work is energy transferred from one object to another - it is not clear to me how either one can be more "primitive" than the other.

Comment: When work is done energy is transferred, however before work is done energy is stored. Energy can only be changed into work so, energy is stored work and so on primitive to work.

Comment: One could argue that energy is not always "stored." E.g., light is energy. Can you store light?

Comment: light doesn't equal energy it caries energy which is then transferred into heat AKA work

Comment: The sentence "*Energy can only be changed into work*" is slightly off - work is not a type of energy and energy does not "change into" work. Energy can be *transfered* as work int the same way that it can be transfered as heat - work is a term for energy transfer, not a term for energy. Thus it seems to me that the causality question isn't fully meaningful.

Comment: The Hamiltonian is a way to prescribe the equations of motion (or more generally, the dynamics). Energy is the value that this Hamiltonian function assumes. Note that you have two ways to go: prescribing a model for the force, to close Newton equations, or to prescribe the Hamiltonian. Both ways are equivalent in classical physics, but the Hamiltonian way is more "cool" as it can be extended to quantum and statistical mechanics.

Answer (score 4):

> can anyone explain to me the relationships between Work, energy, and force in order of causality

By definition, causes must come before effects. They have a definite temporal ordering. So a causal relationship is of the form $$\mathrm{Effect}(t)=f(\mathrm{Cause}(t_r))$$ where $t_r<t$ is called the retarded time.

Energy (potential) is related to force by $$\vec F = -\nabla U$$ which is not a causal equation. So the relationship between force and energy is a logical relationship rather than a causal relationship.

Now, force is related to mechanical work by $$W(t)=\int_{- \infty}^t \vec F(t_r) \cdot \vec v(t_r) \ dt_r$$ so you can consider work to be caused by force.

Because the relationship between force and energy is logical and because force causes mechanical work we would expect to be able to show that energy also causes mechanical work. $$W(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t P(t_r) \ dt_r$$ where $P=\frac{d}{dt}E$. So you could consider energy to cause work, but the relationship is rather awkward. I kind of had to go out of the way to force it into this form. A more natural form is $$W(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t \left(\frac{d}{dt_r} E(t_r) \right) \ dt_r = \int_{E(-\infty)}^{E(t)} dE=E(t)-E(-\infty)$$ which is not as clearly causal, but can probably be argued either way. In any case, it would be difficult to try to argue that work is the cause of energy.

Comment: Indeed causality is difficult here because ultimately, we don't know the source of the energy that existed in the universe whenever it began (if it "began", even that is questionable). And even if we found out, the question arises if work was done to create it..

Answer (score 3):

> Is Energy stored work?

No, energy is not "stored work". Work is a mechanism for transferring energy (the other being heat) from one thing (that loses energy) to another thing (that gains an equal amount of energy). Once that transfer occurs,  any resulting energy that is stored  can no longer be associated with work (or heat).

> explain to me the relationships between Work, energy, and force in
> order of causality.

The verb "cause" means to "make something happen". Nothing makes energy happen. It simply exists. It can neither be created nor destroyed.  On the other hand energy can be moved around and change its "appearance" or form. So we can ask what causes energy to move from place to place and change its appearance.

Work is one such mechanism (the other is heat). I do work when I push an object and displace it perhaps giving it velocity. I transfer energy to that object. In so doing, chemical potential energy of my body winds up in the different form of kinetic energy in the object I displaced.

Finally, what causes the work do be done, i.e., what is it the effect or result of? It is the effect of my exertion of a force that results in a displacement of the object.

In summary, in order of causality I would suggest the diagram below

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is the best answer that i got!

Comment: I like the answer, but I think it is worth adding that the reason that you can exert a force is due to the chemical energy stored in your body. So while the causal chain is correct, it is misleading to think it is a description of reality, i.e. that forces existed before work and energy did.

Comment: @Amit I did say that in third to last paragraph

Comment: Yes I read it, your answer is fantastic. It is only the conclusion that prompted me to make this comment - I would rather understand it as a causal "loop", with energy being linked to the start of the chain, as the cause of force... 
Perhaps I am nitpicky :)

Comment: @Amit that’s a good suggestion. I’ll include it. Thanks

Comment: @Amit Check out added diagram and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I think this is great and really highlights both the inherent circularity of the process and its unifying principle, which is the conservation of energy. 
This gives validity to the apparent circularity - it is only there as a consequence of our describing how this important principle expresses itself in various scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Energy is not stored work.

The thermodynamics definition of work is broader than, and includes, the physics mechanics definition of work.  In thermodynamics Work is defined as "energy transferred, without transfer of mass, across the boundary of a system because of an intensive property difference other than temperature that exists between the system and its surroundings". [Obert, Thermodynamics]  Similarly, Heat is defined as "energy transferred, without transfer of mass, across the boundary of a system solely because of a difference in temperature between the system and its surroundings". [Obert, Thermodynamics]

Both Work and Heat are transitional in nature and neither can be stored in a system.  According to the first law of thermodynamics, Heat and Work can change the energy of the system: kinetic, potential and internal.

Sometimes the internal energy of a system is incorrectly called Heat; the correct term is the internal energy.

*Regarding the "causality among work, energy, and force".*
The above discussion explains energy and work. Work due to a force acting through a distance is special type of work addressed in mechanics. The net work done on a particle by all the external forces is the change in the Kinetic Energy of the particle.  This is special case of the first law, where work is a force acting through a distance and the work only changes kinetic energy. So, the causality is

(1)a net force acts through a distance,

(2) this is work, and

(3) work causes a change in kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

My first response when tacking this question, was that it seems to me that work can be seen as more fundamental than energy, because work has a more precise definition. For example: the work done in moving a particle from point A to point B is defined as the integral of the force along the path taken:
$$ W = \int_A^B{\vec{F}\cdot\vec{dr}}$$

While energy, is usually only defined in terms of the ability of a system to do work. For example, if a tennis ball of mass $m$ has momentum $p$ we know that its kinetic energy is $\frac{p^2}{2m}$. Now suppose that it hits a wall and stops. Naturally, this will generate some heat in the wall. While usually we say that the kinetic energy of the ball was transformed to heat energy, in fact microscopically we can say that the ball did perform work on the wall, which is given exactly by its previous kinetic energy $\frac{p^2}{2m}$, so that this same energy was actually transferred to various microscopic particles which are vibrating faster now in the wall. One way to convince yourself of this, is to imagine this from a frame of reference where the ball is stationary: so the ball is just sitting there, and a wall comes along and whacks it with a momentum $p$, thus imbuing it with kinetic energy $\frac{p^2}{2m}$.
Yes, I know that in Thermodynamics we separate *mechanical work* from *heat transfer* but my understanding is that this is essentially an artificial distinction which helps build the (useful!) theoretical model of Thermodynamics.

The second thing about energy is that it is defined in a more arbitrary way: it doesn't matter if you add on a constant to the energy of a system. For any physical calculation we make, we usually only care about $\Delta{E}$ - the change in the energy, which is just another way of saying that energy from one part of the system has moved to another part (or leaked outside of the system, or entered the system, for non-closed systems).

*But*, after some more thought, I think my immediate instinct was wrong. It's probably not quite right to think that work is more fundamental than energy. True, it does seem to be more well defined *as a mathematical concept*. But physically, I think it is best to say neither energy nor work is more fundamental. The reason is that while work apparently has a more solid mathematical definition, the conceptual basis of energy as a *conserved quantity* is the thing which makes it certainly a more important concept in practice, even if not more fundamental, than work.

Comment: ... If you disagree with what I wrote, I'll be glad to learn from you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've edited my answer, changing it quite a bit and explaining why I did, in the hope that it now contains something useful to another one who may think along the same line as I did.